# Which command run after change Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm reading and learning from the [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), but not building the sample application instead I'm trying to build my own. After generate all the migration and build the main classes for Models I made some modifications to them in order to build relationship between tables now I think that I need to run some command to generate the scaffold again with proper relations, exists such command? I'm lost.

Comment: You question seems to be vague but still. Assuming that you changed some attribs in model. You need to map the routes in your routes.rb file so that you routes are available to the app.after changing your routes.rb you need to run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Ok, I'm newbie with Rails so sometimes I didn't understand what gurus try to teach me anyway my routes.rb look like this http://pastebin.com/Em5DKrMh after that I run the command you suggest me but nothing happen

Comment: It doesnt show it on commandline but you can see the new routes if you do `$ rake routes`

Comment: Ok Dave you're right if I run the command you suggest before the routes are showed but my problem isn't routes ;-) I come from PHP and frameworks like CakePHP and Symfony and there when I have a model with relationship the fields for that relations are showed automatically in forms. For example in my case I have a record and record belongs to country so when I add a new record I should select the country for that record from the same form, right? This is what I'm trying to do here, maybe the title of the post is wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

So, you've modified a model and want to regenerate a scaffold for it?

There is no single command to change to change a scaffold. But you may try to generate a new scaffold for the existing model and throw away the old controller, views and routes. Just generate the scaffold pretending that the model doesn't exists. Rails will notice that the files for the model already exists and will skip generating them. If it generates a new migration, delete it.

Just to be sure, make a backup copy of your code before you try it. ;-)

Comment: See my comment to @Dave this is what I need to do